# What is the relation between $USAT$, $UP$ and $NP=RP$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Definition:

*AtmostONESAT*: SAT instance having promise of $\leq1$ witness.

What is the complexity consequence if an instance of $SAT\in$ *AtmostONESAT* can be decided whether or not there is a witness in $P$?

I believe the problem is similar to UnambiguousSAT (wiki says we get NP=RP if USAT is in P https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Extensions_of_SAT).

Are following correct?

1. Given $\phi\in$*AtmostONESAT* we can decide $\exists x:\phi(x)=TRUE$ in $P$
   $\implies P=UP\wedge NP=RP$?
2. $P=UP\implies NP=RP$?
3. $P=UP\implies$ Given $\phi\in$*AtmostONESAT* we can decide $\exists x:\phi(x)=TRUE$ in $P$?

Comment: What do you mean by "one witness SAT"? Do you mean "unique SAT", determining whether a CNF is satisfiable, under the promise that it has at mot one satisfying assignment?

Comment: Correct and I believe it is UnambiguousSAT (wiki says we get NP=RP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Extensions_of_SAT). Is it 1) P=UP and 2) unrelatedly because of Valiant Vazirani NP=RP (what I am trying to ask is if P=UP has anything to do with NP=RP?)?

Comment: I think Wikipedia has a good summary of current knowledge on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about SAT under the promise that there is at most one satisfying assignment, which you seem to call USAT. That is, you are interested in the promise problem in which the Yes instances are CNFs with a unique satisfying assignment, and the No instances are CNFs with no satisfying assignments.

Valiant and Vazirani, in a [celebrated paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos528/handouts/NP_is_as.pdf), used the [isolation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_lemma) to give a randomized reduction from SAT to this promise problem, thus showing that the promise problem is unlikely to be much easier than SAT itself.

The problem USAT is complete for the class UP (which consists of all problems solvable by an NP machine with the promise that there is at most one accepting computation), hence P=UP iff USAT can be solved in polynomial time.

Comment: Would a P algorithm for "SAT under the promise that there is at most one satisfying assignment" provide P=UP where UP is defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UP_(complexity)?

Comment: Would *what* give P=UP? Also, what is UP?

Comment: As you realized I am aware of the NP=RP result as posted in my comment.

Comment: @Yuval: USAT is not complete for UP. Indeed, UP is not known to have complete problems. USAT should be complete for PromiseUP. See e.g. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/17494/129 and  https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/37703/129.